# Creating an alias name for an object in R

Tags: r, alias

If I have an object with a long_name_for_large_data_frame, can I create an alias name 'd' for the same without duplicating the dataframe to save memory? I checked "?.Alias" where it says this is a defunct funciton. Or should I continue to use:

```
d <- long_name_for_large_data_frame
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That will not create a copy

Comment: OK. Thanks. That is why ".Alias" is not needed. But then how can I manage another data.frame d which I could manipulate without changing original long_name_for_data_frame object?

Comment: Trying this command: a<-5; b<-a; b=10; a;b;  shows that a and b are different objects.

Comment: @mso, `a` and `b` point to the same object in memory, until you change `b` with `b<-10`. R makes a copy of `b` when it's modified. I don't think there's a straightforward way to do what you want, unfortunately.

Comment: Is it possible to create an alias name for a long name? That is my question.

Comment: Just to save you typing? Why is it so long in the first place? You can pass it to a helper function and use parameters names, ie `work<-function(x) x$id; work(long_name_for_large_data_frame)` or something. But "aliases" don't seem to be a thing in R.

Comment: Saving typing and short name is important as is apparent from the name of software itself: 'R' or 'r' !

Comment: Saving typing is a job for the IDE. Use tab completion.

Comment: @wch well... you could use an active binding...

Comment: I have got the same problem

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-r-allow-aliases-without-duplicating-the-object-in-question/12759